# How to Read the Properties in Serilog Context

Tags: serilog

I'm using a Serilog logger that I've enriched with `.Enrich.FromLogContext()`.

I add various properties to the context throughout my application. I'd like to be able to read the properties that are currently on the context. I can use `LogContext.PushProperty()` to add a property to the context, but I haven't found any good way to expose the methods which have been added.

One way around this is to create a filter on the logger and check the `LogEvent.Properties`, and then set some outside variable based on what I find. But this has several disadvantages. It would add this check to every time a message is logged, slowing things down. It is not at all the intention of the filter. And I'm not sure this would be thread safe, so different contexts could update the outside variable at the same time.

Comment: To make sure we're on the same page - you want to be able to read the properties within your application at any time? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That's correct. I can do it by checking the properties of the LogEvent in a log filter and talking to some static variable in the same namespace, but that goes against everything a good OOP boy like me believes in.